# XPath how to select the first element without loading the whole xml?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, libxml2, xpath

Im using libxml2 on the iPhone with the nice Method: PerformXMLXPathQuery from [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html). The problem is how to find out witch xml got sent without first parsing the whole document... I tried to use the @"/" query to retrieve the first element as written on the introduction of Cocoa with Love but unfortunately, the PerformXMLXPathQuery crashes cause of this query!

When I use the @"/*" command the whole tree gets parsed, which is very inefficient in terms of time and memory consumption..

Any Ideas how this works?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: put parent node name for access child nodes

Comment: the root node name is changing depending on the kind of request... My question is how to get the root node name without parsing the whole tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how tight your performance requirements are, but using a SAX parser, such as NSXMLParser, would enable you to quit parsing after you processed the element you're looking for. See the

```
- (void)abortParsing
```

method on the parser, and

```
– parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
– parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
```

on the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I tested the NSXMLParser but it is to slow for my requirements. I solved the problem by testing the request url witch tells me how the xml file will look like.